# task cAT not found in project! CircleCi

Tags: android, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

I am using CircleCi for continuous integration, my circle.yml is

```
test:
  override:
    # start the emulator
    - emulator -avd circleci-android22 -no-audio -no-window:
        background: true
        parallel: true
    # wait for it to have booted
    - circle-android wait-for-boot
    # run tests  against the emulator.
    - ./gradlew cAT
    - ./gradlew publish
```

all these commands are working fine in local, but when I try to build my commits it fails saying task cAT not found. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the project structure was somewhow messed up, I created a new project and pasted my files into that and then I tried to build it circle-ci and it worked fine.